# Handling bad UTF-8 from json,in ruby

Tags: ruby, json, encoding, utf-8

I'm pulling data from remote json at http://hndroidapi.appspot.com/news/format/json/page/?appid=test .  The problem I'm running into is that this API appears to be building the JSON without correctly handling UTF-8 encoding (correct me if I'm wrong here).  For example, part of the result that gets passed right now is

```
{
"title":"IPad - please don&euro;&trade;t ding while you and I are asleep  ",
"url":"http://modern-products.tumblr.com/post/25384729998/ipad-please-dont-ding-while-you-and-i-are-asleep",
"score":"10 points",
"user":"roee",
"comments":"18 comments",
"time":"1 hour ago",
"item_id":"4128497",
"description":"10 points by roee 1 hour ago  | 18 comments"
}
```

Notice the `don&euro;&trade;t`.  And that isn't the only type of character it is choking on.  Is there anything I can do to convert the data into something clean, given that I don't control the API?

Edit:

Here is how I'm pulling down the JSON:

```
hn_url = "http://hndroidapi.appspot.com/news/format/json/page/?appid=test"
  url = URI.parse(hn_url)

  # Attempt to get the json
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(hn_url)
  req.add_field('User-Agent', 'Test')
  res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http| http.request(req) }
  response = res.body
  if response.nil?
    puts "Bad response when fetching HN json"
    return
  end

  # Attempt to parse the json
  result = JSON.parse(response)
  if result.nil?
    puts "Error parsing HN json"
    return
  end
```

Edit 2:

**Just found the API's GitHub page.  Looks like this is an outstanding issue.  Still not sure if there's any workarounds that I can do from my end:**
https://github.com/glebpopov/Hacker-News-Droid-API/issues/4

Comment: It looks like the JSON response body you are receiving may include HTML-safe symbols. I don't see any bad characters at a glance, and I do see that the response `Content-Type` header is set to `application/json; charset=utf-8`, which looks correct. How are you getting the response body? I would try examining the response with a browser tool like `Dev HTTP Client` or CURL, and see if what your application is getting differs from the actual response. If so, you may be handling it incorrectly in your code.

Comment: Thanks.  I added my code up in the edit.  The issue, though, is that they are HTML-safe symbols.  But, it shouldn't be a Euro Symbol and a 'tm' symbol.  It should be an apostrophe.

Comment: You can see the exact response in the console by using `puts res.body`. Are you seeing the funky symbols later via the `result` object?

Comment: I'm not seeing the funky symbols, I'm seeing the HTML-safe versions of them.  So, in the example above, I'm actually seeing `&euro;&trade;` where I should be seeing an apostrophe.  This is in both res.body and later on in the result object.  I think this is because the API is not representing the apostrophe correctly.  So, I was hoping to compensate somehow.

Comment: Ah, WTF-8 with HTML entity escapes, haven't seen that one before. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the JSON response body you are receiving is being received in US-ASCII instead of UTF-8 because `Net::HTTP` purposely doesn't force encoding.

```
1.9.3p194 :044 > puts res.body.encoding
US-ASCII
```

In Ruby 1.9.3, you can force the encoding if you know what it's supposed to be. Try this:

```
response = res.body.force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

The JSON parser should then handle the UTF-8 the way you want it to.

**References**

- [http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/ - Net::HTTP does not handle encoding correctly](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/2567)

Answer (score 4):

Using `force_encoding` seems like the best solution.
Following-up to Kevin Dickerson's answer, here's an explanation of the weirdness.

`Net::HTTP` is sort of a mess.

**On 1.9.3**:

- If the server sends a chunked response, you'd always get ASCII-8BIT. This seems to take precedence over the other scenarios.
- If you call `http.request` with a `Get` object, you'd get US-ASCII. This method does not do compression for you.
- If you call `http.get`, compression is enabled.

  - if the server supports compression, you'd get ASCII-8BIT
  - if the server doesn't send a compressed body, you'd get US-ASCII

You'd get US-ASCII because when `Net::HTTP` creates the buffer string to receive the response, it's created in the interpreter's default source file encoding, which is US-ASCII. (The `net/` source files, don't have the magic encoding comment at the top, so they use ruby's default.)

The decompression produces ASCII-8BIT because it's hardcoded to do that in the `get` method when decompressing.

**On 2.0**, it seems like you always gets UTF-8 back, but this is because that's the default source-file encoding. If you change it via the `-K` option, the response encoding would change accordingly. Try passing `n`, `e`, `s`, `u` to `-K`.